# Query on gcloud compute regions describe us-central1 --flatten='quotas[]' --format='csv[no-heading](quotas.metric,quotas.limit,quotas.usage)'

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I get a list of resources and its quota by running the command as mentioned in the subject. However, I would like to ignore "COMMITED_CPUS" resource from the list. Please suggest how it can be achieved.

```
gcloud compute regions describe us-central1 --flatten='quotas[]' --format='csv[no-heading](quotas.metric,quotas.limit,quotas.usage)'
```

Output is like below:

```
CPUS,2400.0,1412.0
DISKS_TOTAL_GB,204800.0,542.0
STATIC_ADDRESSES,700.0,16.0
IN_USE_ADDRESSES,2300.0,5.0
SSD_TOTAL_GB,204800.0,61020.0
LOCAL_SSD_TOTAL_GB,30000.0,0.0
INSTANCE_GROUPS,2500.0,79.0
INSTANCE_GROUP_MANAGERS,1250.0,0.0
INSTANCES,24000.0,400.0
AUTOSCALERS,1250.0,0.0
REGIONAL_AUTOSCALERS,500.0,0.0
REGIONAL_INSTANCE_GROUP_MANAGERS,500.0,0.0
PREEMPTIBLE_CPUS,10000.0,0.0
NVIDIA_K80_GPUS,64.0,0.0
COMMITTED_CPUS,2400.0,0.0
COMMITTED_LOCAL_SSD_TOTAL_GB,30000.0,0.0
COMMITMENTS,2000.0,0.0
NETWORK_ENDPOINT_GROUPS,2500.0,0.0
INTERNAL_ADDRESSES,200.0,0.0
NVIDIA_P100_GPUS,64.0,0.0
PREEMPTIBLE_LOCAL_SSD_GB,0.0,0.0
PREEMPTIBLE_NVIDIA_K80_GPUS,0.0,0.0
PREEMPTIBLE_NVIDIA_P100_GPUS,0.0,0.0
NVIDIA_P100_VWS_GPUS,0.0,0.0
NVIDIA_V100_GPUS,0.0,0.0
NVIDIA_P4_GPUS,0.0,0.0
NVIDIA_P4_VWS_GPUS,0.0,0.0
PREEMPTIBLE_NVIDIA_V100_GPUS,0.0,0.0
PREEMPTIBLE_NVIDIA_P4_GPUS,0.0,0.0
PREEMPTIBLE_NVIDIA_P100_VWS_GPUS,0.0,0.0
PREEMPTIBLE_NVIDIA_P4_VWS_GPUS,0.0,0.0
INTERCONNECT_ATTACHMENTS_PER_REGION,16.0,0.0
INTERCONNECT_ATTACHMENTS_TOTAL_MBPS,80000.0,0.0
RESOURCE_POLICIES,5.0,0.0
IN_USE_SNAPSHOT_SCHEDULES,20.0,0.0
NVIDIA_T4_GPUS,1.0,0.0
NVIDIA_T4_VWS_GPUS,1.0,0.0
PREEMPTIBLE_NVIDIA_T4_GPUS,1.0,0.0
PREEMPTIBLE_NVIDIA_T4_VWS_GPUS,1.0,0.0
IN_USE_BACKUP_SCHEDULES,20.0,0.0
COMMITTED_NVIDIA_K80_GPUS,0.0,0.0
COMMITTED_NVIDIA_P100_GPUS,0.0,0.0
COMMITTED_NVIDIA_P4_GPUS,0.0,0.0
COMMITTED_NVIDIA_V100_GPUS,0.0,0.0
COMMITTED_NVIDIA_T4_GPUS,0.0,0.0
C2_CPUS,24.0,0.0
N2_CPUS,24.0,0.0
COMMITTED_N2_CPUS,0.0,0.0
COMMITTED_C2_CPUS,0.0,0.0
RESERVATIONS,100.0,0.0
```

Please suggest how can I ignore "COMMITED_CPUS" value from the output using some ignore filter kind of.

Answer (score 1):

In linux you can just use the [grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) command to filter out lines not matching.

Something like this should do:

```
gcloud compute regions describe us-central1 --flatten='quotas[]' --format='csv[no-heading](quotas.metric,quotas.limit,quotas.usage)' | grep -v "COMMITTED_CPUS"
```